# Numpy how to exclude array in vectorization?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a function:

```
import numpy as np

t = np.array([['t1', 0],['t2',0],['t3',1],['t4',1]])
i = np.array(['t3', 't4'])

def myfunc(d, x): 
    return d[:,1][np.where(d[:,0] == x)]

vfunc = np.vectorize(myfunc, excluded=['d'])
vfunc(d=t,x=i)
```

Expected output is: `array(['1', '1'], dtype='<U2')`

Gives the error: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`

I don't see why this doesn't work following exclusion argument in documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

Comment: `vectorize` doesn't improve speed.  But if you insist, what's the result or error?  Make sure you understand the the values passed.  Know, test, don't guess.

Comment: @hpaulj so, appending a list via a list comprehension would be as fast?

Comment: Yes @hpaulj is right. As the documantation says "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."  For further research, you can look into https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

Comment: @hpaulj Just to confirm, do you mean numpy.vectorize will not lead to simd vectorization?? In normal python for-loop vectorization is not possible, but when written in C, it can lead to simd vectorization and simd vectorization can give xtimes speedup depending on how many registers cpu can handle at once, am I correct? I am still trying to understand vectorization, so confirmation is enough you do not have to explain in detail

Comment: @user3329732 thanks to your question, I have better understanding internal details, I added some explanation. Hope it will help you also

Answer (score 3):

As hpaulj said **Know, test, don't guess.**

It was bit difficult to pin point, but here it is.

Docs says `By default, pyfunc is assumed to take scalars as input and output.`

To remove this error add otypes argument, you will not get your exact output but numpy can atleast figure out correctly what it needs to return

```py
vfunc = np.vectorize(myfunc, excluded=['d'], otypes='O')
```

```
signature : string, optional

    Generalized universal function signature, e.g., (m,n),(n)->(m) for
 vectorized matrix-vector multiplication. If provided, pyfunc will be called
 with (and expected to return) arrays with shapes given by the size of
 corresponding core dimensions. By default, pyfunc is assumed to take scalars
 as input and output.
```

**Below is detailed reason for proposed solution**

Your function does not return a scalar output, it returns a vector output for each input scalar. While input is a scalar (t3,) and (t4,), there actual output are vector `array(['1'], dtype='<U2')`, `array(['1'], dtype='<U2')]` respectively.

Since you don't specify the signature, by default numpy thinks outputs are scalar and tries to put them in numpy array with dtypes as dtype of input(But actual dtype is object), trying to make a vector.

That is the error `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`, because your ufunc output is vector for each input scalar and not a scalar and also no signature is defined(reason for why numpy assumes output is scalar).

Also look at example similar to yours in numpy vectorize docs, numpy uses scalar return type and not vector

```py
def mypolyval(p, x):

    _p = list(p)

    res = _p.pop(0)

    while _p:

        res = res*x + _p.pop(0)

    return res

vpolyval = np.vectorize(mypolyval, excluded=['p'])

vpolyval(p=[1, 2, 3], x=[0, 1])
array([3, 6])
```

I come to this conclusion through debugging, since myself don't have enough experience using vectorization.

While debugging in [function_base.py](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/lib/function_base.py), at line [L2257](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L2257) outputs are accumulated and has value `array([array(['1'], dtype='<U2'), array(['1'], dtype='<U2')], dtype=object)`. Then at [L2260](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L2260) numpy tries to convert them into required dtype, but fails because it was assuming sequence of scalars, but got a sequence of sequence.

Just put a breakpoint in vscode and try to see variable outputs you can figure out.

Answer (score 2):

`np.vectorize` does "vectorize" in the sense that it allows you to pass array(s) to a function that otherwise only works with scalar values.  But it can be tricky to use right, and it does not improve performance.  It does not compile your function, so low level concepts of 'vectorization' do not apply.

---

```
In [1]: t = np.array([['t1', 0],['t2',0],['t3',1],['t4',1]])
   ...: i = np.array(['t3', 't4'])
   ...: 
In [2]: def myfunc(d, x):
   ...:     return d[:,1][np.where(d[:,0] == x)]
   ...: 
   ...: vfunc = np.vectorize(myfunc, excluded=['d'])
```

Your problem - with **full traceback**

```
In [3]: vfunc(d=t,x=i)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-3-ea7904300378>", line 1, in <module>
    vfunc(d=t,x=i)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2163, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2249, in _vectorize_call
    res = asanyarray(outputs, dtype=otypes[0])
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

What does your function produce?  arrays!

```
In [4]: myfunc(t,i[0])
Out[4]: array(['1'], dtype='<U21')
In [5]: myfunc(t,i[1])
Out[5]: array(['1'], dtype='<U21')
```

Lets try again, this time displaying the values passed to the function, and setting `otypes`.  Since you read enough to use `exclude` you must have come across the `otypes` parameter as well.  This issue often causes problems for SO questioners.  (Based on the trial calculation your `vectorize` had set `otypes` to `str`, resulting in the `ValueError`)

```
In [6]: def myfunc(d, x):
   ...:     print(d,x)
   ...:     return d[:,1][np.where(d[:,0] == x)]
   ...: 
   ...: vfunc = np.vectorize(myfunc, excluded=['d'], otypes=['O'])
In [7]: vfunc(d=t,x=i)
[['t1' '0']
 ['t2' '0']
 ['t3' '1']
 ['t4' '1']] t3
[['t1' '0']
 ['t2' '0']
 ['t3' '1']
 ['t4' '1']] t4
Out[7]: 
array([array(['1'], dtype='<U21'), array(['1'], dtype='<U21')],
      dtype=object)

In [8]: np.hstack(_)
Out[8]: array(['1', '1'], dtype='<U21')
```

`excluded` did work, the whole `d` was passed each time.  An alternative would be to define the function to use a global array, `t`, rather than expect it as argument

```
def myfunc(x):
   print(x)
   return t[:,1][np.where(t[:,0] == x)]
```

Let's generalize the arguments a bit

```
In [12]: t = np.array([['t1', 0],['t2',0],['t3',1],['t4',1],['t4',10]])
    ...: i = np.array(['t3', 't4','t5'])
    ...: 
    ...: 
In [13]: vfunc(d=t,x=i)
[['t1' '0']
 ['t2' '0']
 ['t3' '1']
...
Out[13]: 
array([array(['1'], dtype='<U21'), array(['1', '10'], dtype='<U21'),
       array([], dtype='<U21')], dtype=object)
```

the result is 3 arrays with different sizes.  `hstack` would still work.

But with just one 1d argument, `i`, it would be just as easy, and faster, to use:

```
In [14]: np.array([myfunc(t,j) for j in i])
[['t1' '0']
 ['t2' '0']
 ['t3' '1']
 ....
<ipython-input-14-207a42bdb1fb>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  np.array([myfunc(t,j) for j in i])
Out[14]: 
array([array(['1'], dtype='<U21'), array(['1', '10'], dtype='<U21'),
       array([], dtype='<U21')], dtype=object)
```

### vectorization

This can have many meanings.  `simd vectorization` is a new one for me, but then I haven't done low level ('C') programming in years.  `np.vectorize` does not compile or alter your function in anyway.  It has a clear performance disclaimer (I suppose it could be in bold and at the start of the docs).  It's intended primarily for functions that take scalar values, and return similarly simple results, and is most useful when it takes several arguments, and for which you want to take advantage of `numpy` `broadcasting`.

```
The vectorized function evaluates `pyfunc` over successive tuples
of the input arrays like the python map function, except it uses the
broadcasting rules of numpy.
```

Informally (and without documented justification) we talk about `numpy` 'vectorization' as a way of making big performance gains.  What that really means is moving iterations from the Python level (for loops, list comprehensions) to compiled numpy methods.  It's interpreter vs compiler difference.  `np.vectorize`, despite the name, does not do this.

A way of using numpy methods is:

```
In [17]: t[:,0]==i[:,None]
Out[17]: 
array([[False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False]])
```

By adding a dimension to `i`, we can test `t[:,0]` against all `i` values at once.  Applying `where` to that to get the indices:

```
In [19]: np.where(t[:,0]==i[:,None])
Out[19]: (array([0, 1, 1]), array([2, 3, 4]))
```

and using that to index `t`:

```
In [20]: t[_[1],1]
Out[20]: array(['1', '1', '10'], dtype='<U21')
```

Or we could use the boolean mask in Out[17] row by row:

```
In [21]: [t[j,1] for j in _17]
Out[21]: 
[array(['1'], dtype='<U21'),
 array(['1', '10'], dtype='<U21'),
 array([], dtype='<U21')]
```

With the possible mix of array sizes, it is hard to do this without some sort of python level iteration.  The fast numpy operations work on multidimensional arrays, not on "ragged" ones.

Answer (score 1):

I could be missing something, but the other answers seem to be really overcomplicating this.  You just need 'd' to be a keyword argument, as the vectorize method seems to only be capable of interfering with the keywords dictionary.

I was dealing with this problem myself and switching the argument to a keyword fixed it instantly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).